# How to extract words of constant length form a paragraph?

Tags: java, android, substring, text-extraction, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to extract the words form a paragraph/string. I searched it out many where but didn't find relative material. I want to extract words of length 4 from

***"I want to have alot of moneys when I am older probably e1X2"***

I'm trying to extract using

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s  = "I want to have alot of moneys when I am older probably.";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z']{4,}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            words.add(m.group());
        }

    System.out.println(words);
```

> The output which am I getting right now

```
[want, have, alot, moneys, when, older, probably]
```

**but the output must be**

```
[want, have, alot, when]
```

Comment: Words can contain digits or not ?

Comment: Just change {4,} to {4}

Comment: Yes, it can contain digits also

Comment: @RadheAnkit - see my updated question

Comment: I think you probably need to add look-ahead and look-behind to ensure that that there is a whitespace character (or string start or end) separating the word

Comment: https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind

Comment: @ControlAltDel - Dear can you please type some code to get the problem solved?

Comment: Not a bug, but shouldn't it be "money" in the sentence? And "a lot" is two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way to get the result :

```
List<String> words=new ArrayList<String>(); 
    String s="I want to have alot of of moneys when I am older probably";
    String str[]=s.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i].length()==4)
            words.add(str[i]);
    }
    System.out.print(words);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s  = "I want to have alot of moneys when I am older probably.";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{4}\\b");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            words.add(m.group());
        }

        System.out.println(words);
    }
```

**Output:** `[want, have, alot, when]`

**Explanation:**

1. `\b`  matches a word boundary.

Comment: Thank bro your answer also worked but I'm bound to accept on first come first serve basis. But you deserve +1

Comment: @IrfanAkram hehe no problem bro. I got a bit late because I wanted to solve your problem with regex only since you were using that in your question. Anyway thanks for an upvote. Better luck next time!!!

Answer (score 0):

You want make it with regex?

Because you didn't put the "()" that indicates a group, as you called "m.group()" you need this syntax.

Work your regex here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/). After that put it in your Java program.

You could as well split the string with white space and filter the resulting array with only the elements with desired length.

Answer (score 0):

You need look behind and look ahead in your regex

Your original:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z']{4,}");
```

With look ahead and look behind:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=\s)[a-zA-Z']{4,}(?=\s)");
```

Now that the lookaheads and behinds have been added, there could be an issue with beginning and end of string not matching. Add a space on both sides of the matched string and it should work

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```java
/* Required imports:
 * import java.util.Arrays;
 * import java.util.List;
 * import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 */
List<String> words = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\b"))
                           .filter(word -> word.length() == 4)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The text is split into individual words.
Only words whose length is 4 pass through the filter.
All the four-letter words are collected into a list.